# How to get the value of a $_POST, if it is an array in PHP?

Tags: php

[image: I added an image showing the response when I use var_dump($emails);]Let's say I have an array of emails

```
['email1', 'email2'...'email(n)'];
```

submitted to a form,

How do I store this values into a variable, 
ie,

```
$emails = $_POST['emails'];
```

but this does not work as it sees the value ($emails) as a string rather than an array.

I have also tried

```
$emailsArray = explode(' ', $emails);
```

while the $emailsArray is of type array , it fails cause it groups all elements as a single string

Remember the email is dynamic and cannot be predicted its length.

Comment: How is that array submitted from the form?

Comment: I am currently building an API to send individual emails to every single email, I am using Jquery $.post API to send the array to the API

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($_POST)` **in the question by editing it**

Comment: string(57) "['email1@gmail.com','email@gmail.com','email3@gmail.com']"

Comment: **in the question by editing the question...**

Comment: you have too many unclosed questions, IMHO. Stack works both ways. Solution given = good rep given on both sides of the street, as it were. Accepting the ones that solved them, should be marked as solved.

Comment: explode(',',$emails); each mail id are separated by ',' not ' ' (space) or you can use JSON decode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are receiving a JSON string, you need to decode it like this:

```
$emails = json_decode($_POST['emails']);
```

Here is the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) .

Comment: @CWilliams I noticed a lot of unclosed questions, please close a question when you find the right answer, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a 100% clear how you send the array, but if you use `var_dump($_POST)` you should be able to see the contents of `$_POST`.
The output should be something like this:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(6) "email1"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "email2"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "email3"
}
```

The key to use is in the `[]`. So in this case you would use `$_POST[1]` to get `"email1"`. If you don't understand you could send the output of `var_dump($_POST)`, or send the code from which you send the array.

EDIT: Mehdi just asked the same question, and apparrently your question is how you can convert a string to an array.

There is probably already an answer for that somewhere, but here is a way to do it:

```
$array = explode(',', trim($_POST['emails'], "[]"));
```

It basically removes the `[]` brackets (with `trim)`, then cuts the string into pieces divided by the commas (with `explode`). You still have the `'` quotation marks to handle, but with what I've given you you should be able to figure out how to do that on your own.

EDIT2: Or you could just use `json_decode` like the answer of Mehdi...

Comment: This worked like charm, for some reasons a lot of people downvoted this question, but trust me you have saved me a lot of time thanks. Thanks once again